# Update salary record for employee

Tags: ssms-2014

I've got a table with a list of employees names, their employee ID and their salary.

I'd like to update the salary for one of the employees (Stacy) from 73000 to 90000 - see sample data below:

employee_id first_name  salary
2009        Stacy       73000

I was thinking of writing something like this:

```
update salary from employees where first_name = 'stacy'
```

But does any how where I should incorporate the updated salary?

The table is called 'employees' and the field I'd like to update is the salary field.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE employees SET salary = 90000 WHERE first_name = 'stacy'